# Delete related models in django through a ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models

I have two Django models related through a `ManyToManyField`:

```python
class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)

class Card(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    boards = models.ManyToManyField(Board)
```

As you can see, a `Card` can appear in several `Board`s. The algorithm I'd like to write is as follows:

1. If I delete all the `Card`s in a `Board`, it's ok. The `Board` remains empty, and that's all.
2. If I delete a `Board`, all the `Cards` that are not attached to another `Board` must be deleted.

My first idea is override the `pre_delete` signal on `Board`, but I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it board `.delete()`. Something like this:

```
def delete(*args, **kwargs):
    self.card_set.annotate(board_count=Count('boards')).filter(board_count=1).delete()
    super(Board, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

This will select all of the boards related cards, and then filter on out the cards that are associated with more than one board. (You already know one of the boards is the current board) And then delete them.

It is also important to remember that this will only be called when you call `.delete()` on a single board. Not on a queryset.

EDIT: since `.delete()` is not called when calling `.delete()` on a query set, I think the `pre_delete` signal would be a better choice:

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Board)
def delete_associated_cards(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    instance.card_set.annotate(board_count=Count('boards')).filter(board_count=1).delete()
```

Comment: [In the Django documentation][1] it says:

Note that the delete() method for an object is not necessarily called when deleting objects in bulk using a QuerySet. To ensure customized delete logic gets executed, you can use pre_delete and/or post_delete signals.

  [1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods

Comment: You are right. Sorry, I was thinking about `pre_save` and `post_save`. In this case, you should use `pre_delete` But the same code should work -- just move it to `pre_save`